# Toggling HTML5 tooltip with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When leaving an `input` element with a `required` attribute empty, a tooltip appears (using Chrome): "Please fill out this field".

```
<input type="text" name="foo" required />
```

[image]

Is there a Javascript function that activates that tooltip manually an any location with any content? (without creating it yourself)?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter But that gives no control over the tooltip whatsoever. I'm looking for a solution that makes me in control over the position and content of the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible anymore: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050

One of the chromium developers explicitly say:

> Web authors need to build their own UI from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only change the text of the tooltip.
Try listening to `invalid` event

```
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("invalid", function (e) {
    if (e.target.value == "") {
        e.target.setCustomValidity('Hey! "' + e.target.value + '" is not a valid username.');
    }
});
```

I didn't test it for browser compatibility but I guess it's a new feature and might be not well supported yet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. Could you illustrate this with a fiddle?

Comment: I'm actually working on it. I didn't notice that you wanted to show the tooltip on input blur.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmaticaly click "Submit" button - this will trigger the validation and tooltip, e.g. with HTML like this

```
<form id="bla">
   <input type="text" required />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

calling

```
document.getElementById("submit").click();
```

will display the tooltip for empty fields.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bmF4N/

If you're looking for more control - you may need to look into custom validators, for example http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/